# Rails - capistrano and chmod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ubuntu-10.04

I want to use chmod via capistrano to add permission for folder. For example, i want to do that:

```
chmod 777 -R /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current/log/
```

So, i want to do that via capistrano's task. I tried that:

```
desc "Fix permission"
   task :fix_permissions, :roles => [ :app, :db, :web ] do
     run "#{try_sudo} chmod 777 -R #{current_path}/log"
   end

  after "deploy:update_code", :fix_permissions
```

But it doesn't work. Permissions of the folder are same:

```
$ ls -alh /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current/log/
total 1008K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K 2012-02-03 20:22 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4.0K 2012-01-25 20:50 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 419K 2012-02-03 14:35 development.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 530K 2012-02-03 20:16 production.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2012-02-02 14:21 searchd.development.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15K 2012-02-03 20:22 searchd.log
-rw------- 1 root root    6 2012-02-03 20:22 searchd.production.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19K 2012-02-03 18:07 searchd.query.log
```

If i try to print chmod manually via ssh it works:

```
$ chmod 777 -R /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current/log/
$ ls -alh /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current/log/
total 1008K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K 2012-02-03 20:22 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4.0K 2012-01-25 20:50 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 419K 2012-02-03 14:35 development.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 530K 2012-02-03 20:16 production.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2012-02-02 14:21 searchd.development.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15K 2012-02-03 20:22 searchd.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 2012-02-03 20:22 searchd.production.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19K 2012-02-03 18:07 searchd.query.log
```

How can i write right task for capistrano to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the hook to after deploy:symlink, I think you are updating permissions in the 'previous' current dir. On a side note: deploy:symlink will soon change to deploy:create_symlink, keep that in mind if this breaks after upgrading capistrano to 2.10 or higher.