# Paperclip files get deleted after each deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, paperclip, assets

I use the Paperclip gem to store pictures, and on localhost it works perfectly. However, any pictures I add to my live app get deleted after every deploy.

I use Git to deploy. Here's my deployment process:

```
$ bundle exec cap production deploy
$ ssh root@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
$ chmod -R 777 /rails_apps/app/releases
$ cd /rails_apps/app/current
$ cp config/database.yml.sample config/database.yml
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Has anyone else run into something like this?

---

**UPDATE:**

This is not a duplicate, because the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807428/capistrano-deleting-paperclip-images), which is to add this line to my deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('public/system')
```

causes Paperclip to break entirely. Previously I had had an issue with not having permission to add images with Paperclip, resulting in this error:

```
Errno::EACCES in UsersController#update
Permission denied - /rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public/system/users/avatars/000/000/562
```

But running this command on my server fixes the permissions:

```
chmod -R 777 /rails_apps/website/releases
```

However, modifying my deploy.rb file as shown above, causes the `chmod -R 777` command to no longer work, and I once again don't have permission to add images, resulting in the same "Permission denied" error.

So that question does not supply a valid solution to my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capistrano Deleting Paperclip Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807428/capistrano-deleting-paperclip-images)

Comment: @JustinLicata Not a duplicate; I edited to explain why.

Comment: This isn't an _answer_ per se, but rather a different solution. Have you thought about storing your images on an S3 bucket? There are a number of advantageous reasons to do that.

Comment: Also, did you create a symlink to that shared directory? `ln -s /rails_apps/website/shared/public/system /rails_apps/website/current/public/system`. Here is another [good post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133367/rails-capistrano-and-chmod) on how to update permissions after Capistrano deploys.

Comment: have you considered [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)? it may be helpful to add images and have them stick with your project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do here:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('public/system')
```

is actually symlinking your "public/system" folder from `/rails_apps/website/releases/20150807211111/public/system` to `/rails_apps/website/shared/public/system` , so that the pictures are always stored in the shared directory, and not lost on deploy. So what you should actually do is set the proper rights for the shared folder.

Comment: Oh, so what I actually need to do is to run something like `chmod -R 777 /rails_apps/website/shared`, instead of `chmod -R 777 /rails_apps/website/releasese`?

Comment: It should work then yes, although i find `chmod 777` a bit open for what you want to do. It would be better to leave the original rights and just `chown` everything inside /rails_apps/website/ to the user that is running the app.

Comment: Would you think `chmod -R 777` is appropriate if I want anybody to be able to add an image?

Comment: Don't mix up system permissions with your permissions in the application. As the system user, that starts the rails process writes the images, only this system user needs permissions set. What you do inside your app (for example with devise users) is up to you.

Comment: `chown -R user:user /rails_apps/website/` where `user` is the system user that runs the rails app. Simple as that.

Comment: What negative effects could I get from running `chmod`? I alone have access to my server and to my machine.

Comment: you never know. Certainly I would not give executable rights to anyone for the files. Its always good to minimize risks.

Answer (score 5):

best way to store your images is a place like [SWS Secure, Durable & Highly-Scalable Object Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

to set this up is really simple

```
# Gemfile
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk
```

in your config/environments/production.rb

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

If you are having issues uploading images please read the following two configuration sections.

If you continue to have issues please see the Paperclip documentation page for detailed configuration options.

To override the default URL structure and place the bucket’s name “domain-style” in the URL (e.g. your_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com). These options can be placed in the [paperclip_defaults configuration](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) hash shown above, or into an initializer.

```
#config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

I hope that this helps.

Happy Hacking

Comment: Interesting thought. Am I correct in thinking this method isn't free?

Comment: that is correct its not free but its really inexpensive https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/  art $0.0100 per GB

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using capistrano, what about setting up shared children like:

```
#config/deploy.rb
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}
```

And then just tell to capistrano to set up the shared folders properly bu running:

```
cap deploy:setup
```

[Source](http://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-3-how-to-add-a-new-folder-to-the-shared-directory-in-capistrano-2-15-5)

Comment: I'm fairly inexperienced with capistrano and I know a lot can go very wrong with servers...is there any chance these commands could lead to undesirable consequences, like deleting data?

Comment: @JoeMorano If you read the source article I mentioned you can find this:
`"[cap deploy:setup] prepares one or more servers for deployment. … It is safe to run this task on servers that have already been set up; it will not destroy any deployed revisions or data."`

Comment: Also, if you don't want to do this, you might just simply copy the images directory to the shared directory and then create a symlink for yourself. But you need to add the symlink as a post deploy step, to be done after each deploy. Also the above code does the same.

Answer (score 0):

**You may be hosting your app on a stack that does not allow you to store files directly to the filesystem at runtime.**

Services such as Heroku will only allow you to temporarily store files to the system in memory, any updates, restarts, redeploys will clearly wipe this out.  I'm sure this is the case for many other services out there as well.

If using such a service, you need to store your dynamic assets on a separate service such as AWS-S3 (Amazon's Simple Storage Service).  You store the files there, and the information such as the url's to these assets in your databse

---

*If you identify where you are hosting your app, I can be more detailed in the solution.*