# How to preserve multiple directories through capistrano deployments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I have a simple rails app at the moment that I would like to preserve two distinct directories through Capistrano deployments.

So far I have tried the following,

```
# see this SO answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32011351/708807
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('tmp/uploads')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('public/spree')
```

but the images in the `public/spree` are not persisting through Capistrano deployments.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried set: :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, ['tmp/uploads', 'public/spree']) ??

Comment: @JuanManuelRodulfoSalcedo I have not, let me give that a shot.

Comment: @JuanManuelRodulfoSalcedo that did the trick, thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, ['tmp/uploads', 'public/spree'])
```

is what solved the problem.